How to compute $\lim_{z\to 0}(1+z)^{1/z}$ in the complex plane?
How to compute $\lim_{z\to 0}(1+z)^{1/z}$ in the complex plane?
I think I need to choose the principal branch since it is multiple-valued.
Is it a good way to try with $\epsilon-\delta$ definition or with the Squeeze Theorem?

As a first step, perhaps that you could explain us the meaning of $(1+z)^{1/z}$, when $z$ is an arbitrary complex number.

You can assume $z=x+iy$ and compute it as a two variable limit.

Show us your work and we can understand better what are your doubts
